# Proving Schwarz's inequality

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, inequality

I'm studying about Markov processes from book: *Daniel W. Stroock
An Introduction
to Markov Processes*. In the first chapter of the book there is the following exercise:

> Schwarz's inequality comes in many forms, the most elementary of which
>   is the statement that, for any $\{a_n:n\in \mathbb{Z}\} \subseteq
>  \mathbb{R}$ and $\{b_n:n\in \mathbb{Z}\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$,
>
> $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} |a_n b_n| \leq \sqrt{\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}
>  a_n^2}\sqrt{\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} b_n^2}.$$
>
> Moreover, when the right hand is finite, then
>
> $$\left|\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} a_n b_n\right| =
>  \sqrt{\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} a_n^2}\sqrt{\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} b_n^2}$$
>
> if and only if there is an $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ for which either
>   $b_n =\alpha a_n$, $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ or  $a_n =\alpha b_n$, $n\in
>  \mathbb{Z}$. Here is an outline of one proof of these statements.
>
> (a) Begin by showing that it suffices to treat the case in which
>   $a_n=0=b_n$ for all but a finite number of $n$'s.
>
> (b) Given a real, quadratic polynomial $P(x)=Ax^2+2Bx+C$, use the
>   quadratic formula to see that $P\geq 0$ everywhere if and only if
>   $C\geq 0 $ and $B^2\leq AC$. Similarly, show that $P > 0$ everywhere
>   if and only if $C > 0 $ and $B^2< AC$.
>
> (c) Assuming that $a_n=0=b_n$ for all, but a finite number of $n$'s,
>   set $P(x)=\sum_n(a_nx+b_n)^2$, and apply (b) to get the desired
>   conclusions. Finally, use (a) to remove the restriction of the $a_n$'s
>   and $b_n$'s.

I have solved (b) and (c) parts of this exercise but part (a) is confusing me for some reason. **How should I approach part (a) of this problem?**

Comment: You can use the following *definition* of $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}c_n$, when $c_n\ge0$ for all $n$: $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}c_n=\sup\{\sum_{n\in F}c_n\colon F\subset\mathbb{Z}\text{ is finite}\}$. Playing around with the definition of the supremum, starting on the right hand side, will get you there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have shown (b) and (c) whenever the series are finite. Now, to obtain the result for an infinite series, you need to prove:

$$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N |a_n b_n| \le \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^N a_n^2}\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^N b_n^2}$$

But if you have shown that the inequality holds for all finite $N$, then it also holds in the limit $N\rightarrow \infty$ (provided that the sums converge). See for example the Sandwich theorem, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1349875/10063.

And similarly for (c) ...

Answer (score 1):

a) says that we can work with quadratic inequality because in this case $A\neq0$.

Otherwise we can not use $\Delta$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different take:
The *assumption* means that
$$\sum_{n\in F} |a_n b_n| \leq \sqrt{\sum_{n\in F}
 a_n^2}\sqrt{\sum_{n\in F} b_n^2}$$
holds for every *finite* set $F\subset\mathbb{Z}$.
Clearly,
$$\sqrt{\sum_{n\in F}
 a_n^2}\sqrt{\sum_{n\in F} b_n^2}
\leq\sqrt{\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}
 a_n^2}\sqrt{\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} b_n^2},$$
and combining the two inequalities, we have
$$\sum_{n\in F} |a_n b_n| \leq \sqrt{\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}
 a_n^2}\sqrt{\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} b_n^2}.$$
Since $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} |a_n b_n|=\sup\Bigl\{\sum_{n\in F} |a_n b_n|\colon F\subset\mathbb{Z}\text{ is finite}\Bigr\},$$
we're done.